# Haxe libraries "Class not found : openfl.Assets"

Tags: haxe

**BIG UPDATE**

Today, I wanted to work on something else and I realized that Haxe was completley down. In fact, I can't compile any library. Even openfl doesn't work.

I tried to uninstall/reinstall Haxe without success.

---

I was currently working on my library project. Everything was working fine and suddenly, it became impossible to compile anything.

I restricted the problem to a minimal one.

So here is the project tree under haxe/lib folder near to every other libraries

```
beluga/current
beluga/0,1,0/haxelib.json
beluga/0,1,0/test/Test.hx
```

> Note: I  tried to rename the folder to `0.1.1` and haxe threw me the following error
>
> > **Library beluga version 0.1.0 is not installed**

The content of the file Test.hx

```
package test;

class Test {
}
```

Now, if I create a new project. If I try to compile with

```
haxe -cp src -lib beluga -php bin -main Main
```

Please note that this works

```
haxe -cp src -cp ../../../lib/beluga/0,1 -php bin -main Main
```

It does not say that the beluga library is not found so it should be properly installed. Also, in FlashDevelop, the auto completion works fine. However, with a main like this:

```
package ;
import test.Test;

class Main {
    static function main() { }
}
```

I have the following error:

> src/Main.hx:2: characters 7-16 : Class not found : test.Test

Finally, the content of `haxelib.json`:

```
{
  "name": "beluga",
  "license": "GPL",
  "tags": ["php","neko","framework","game"],
  "description": "\r\n\t\tBeluga is a video game framework.\r\n\t",
  "contributors": ["masadow"],
  "releasenote": "Initial version, not released yet",
  "version": "0.1",
  "url": "http://myproject.org",
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

You can find the github repositories of the project here

- [Library](https://github.com/Masadow/Beluga)
- [Demo project](https://github.com/Masadow/BelugaDemo)

Any idea ?

Comment: Which version of Haxe, and which version of Haxelib are you using? I ask because you're using "haxelib.json", which suggests haxelib 3, but your version number does not match Haxelib's semantic versioning... it should be "0.1.0". Not sure if that would make a difference

Comment: @JasonO'Neil haxelib 3.0.0 and haxe 3.0.0. I never had any problem before and didn't made any update recently. That would be weird ?

Comment: I'm just throwing out ideas here. Perhaps try a `haxelib selfupdate` to get the latest haxelib.  And then try change the version to `0.1.0`.  I'm not sure if it would make a difference, but it is worth a shot. If that doesn't work, perhaps you can post the code to Github so me or @back2dos can take a look?

Comment: I changed it into 0.1.0 and it did not change anything. I also updated haxelib. I edit the question to link the repositories of the current project. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is extremely weird and I think it is a Haxe compiler issue.

I'm using Windows and I wanted to add some routine stuff (like "doskey" commands) to my shell.

So I've add my custom routine file like that

```
reg add "hkcu\software\microsoft\command processor" /v Autorun /t reg_sz /d c:\bin\autorun.cmd
```

This is actually breaking the Haxe compiler.

Here is the autorun.cmd content :

```
@echo off
cls
doskey /macrofile=c:\bin\cmd_alias.txt
```

And the alias content :

```
ls=ls --color $*
ll=ls -l --color $*
```

It was simply an incompatibility between AUTORUN reg key of cmd.exe and Haxe compiler

Answer (score 1):

Try `haxelib path beluga` and see whether it gives you the right path (you can also add that output to your compiler args instead of `-lib beluga` to eliminate haxelib as an error source).

It's also possible that your haxelib.json specifies a `classPath` other then the root.

Comment: I already check that and it redirect to the good path. I edit to show the content of the json file which seems good to me.

I don't want to get rid of `-lib beluga`. If there is an error, I would prefer to correct it before sharing my library to others.

Comment: @Masadow: I understand that. Still, I think it's important to understand where the error comes from. If you don't use -lib but add the arguments directly, you should see whether the error comes from haxelib or your code.

Comment: I edited my question. Actually, remplacing `-lib` by a `-cp` works.